# Scroll fixed content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to detect which `div` is bigger out of two columns. The smaller `div` gets a class of `.js-small-content`. That class has a `position:fixed` on it.

However the issue that I am having is that I need to be able to scroll the fixed content. Which I understand sounds weird as why would I want to scroll something thats fixed?

If you take a look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tvq36qh/6/) you will see that I need to be able to scroll the cat content so I can see all the images.

[This is an example](http://minimalissimo.com/acne-studios-in-seoul/) of the effect that I am after. You can see that the small content allows you to scroll it first and then once it has all been viewed it then fixes to the bottom of the content and continues scrolling the images on the left.

I think I may need to do something with the viewport on scroll but I'm not sure how to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
var a = document.querySelector('#single__images');
var b = document.querySelector('#single__content');

var aH = a.scrollHeight;
var bH = b.scrollHeight;

(aH > bH ? b.classList.add("js-small-content") : a.classList.add("js-small-content"));
```

HTML:

```
<article>
   <div id="single__image"><img src="#"/></div>
   <div id="single__content">Text goes here</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked really long for this, as was challenging for me. Finally made it.

According to you, you want to **add class and remove class to smaller one among two `div's`**. Which i have accomplished(but its' not right way to do at all)  with **my own other way**.

I have made the **smaller div to stop scroll** when reaches **at three fourth of window position from top.**

[JSFiddle : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwx90t7b/1/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    var divImg = document.getElementById("single__images").id;
 var divCont = document.getElementById("single__content").id;
    
    // Height of single__content
    var hC = $("#" + divCont).outerHeight(); 
     
    // Height of single__images
    var hI = $("#" + divImg).outerHeight(); 
    
    // Check out the smaller one
    if(hC<hI)
    {
        var samllOne = document.getElementById("single__content").id;
    }
    else
    {
     var samllOne = document.getElementById("single__images").id;
    }

    // Height of Smaller Div
    var h = $("#" + samllOne).outerHeight(); 
    
    
    
    // Position of Smaller Div from top
    var topPos = $("#" + samllOne).position();
    var topPos = topPos.top; 

    // Height of Smaller Div
    var h = $("#" + samllOne).outerHeight(); 

    // Div Height + TOP Space from from Body
    var bottomCont = topPos + h;
 
    // Checks current Scroll
    var curScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    var windowH = $(window).innerHeight();
    var windowMid = windowH / 2;
    var midOfMid = windowMid / 2;
    
    var threeFourth = windowMid + midOfMid;
    var bottomTouch = h - threeFourth;
    
 if(curScroll >= bottomTouch)
    {
      $("#" + samllOne).css({position: "fixed", top: "-" + bottomTouch + "px" });
    }
    else
    {
      $("#" + samllOne).css({position: "relative", top: "0px" });     
    }
});
```

```css
article {
    position:relative;
}

#single__images {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#single__content {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
   <div id="single__images">
       <div class="inner">
       <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
       <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
       <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
       <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
       <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="single__content">
       <div class="inner">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin commodo sed libero non lobortis. Aliquam aliquam vulputate felis. Phasellus hendrerit tellus ut libero bibendum rhoncus. Cras et ultricies neque. Curabitur posuere leo scelerisque mattis semper. In et arcu dictum, dictum libero ac, blandit nibh. Ut pharetra velit non blandit pretium. Suspendisse malesuada sodales orci, nec interdum ligula vestibulum ut. Mauris libero massa, tempus vel eleifend sit amet, efficitur nec sem.

Vivamus pretium malesuada ligula quis pulvinar. Duis ornare at massa et elementum. In ac consectetur turpis. Duis in velit nec nunc feugiat semper at in augue. Praesent ut odio quam. Ut faucibus eget massa a suscipit. Mauris fermentum est sed hendrerit lacinia. Mauris ac eleifend dolor. Phasellus rutrum volutpat efficitur. Maecenas vestibulum auctor massa, non dapibus diam laoreet id. Curabitur tincidunt massa vitae nibh varius iaculis. Duis sit amet nisi tempor, vestibulum ipsum at, rutrum purus. Mauris accumsan vulputate convallis. Morbi hendrerit ultrices erat, eu mollis neque faucibus id. Fusce sed magna semper justo placerat placerat quis eget augue.

Phasellus fermentum laoreet felis nec efficitur. Donec ultrices rutrum auctor. Duis faucibus rutrum tortor, ut eleifend libero pellentesque vitae. In nec ullamcorper justo. Donec eget aliquam est. Phasellus semper aliquam odio eu interdum. Praesent ultricies lectus nibh, ac bibendum lacus tempor sed. In ac ultrices sapien, vitae iaculis diam. Nullam pharetra lacus quis facilisis finibus. In a nisl aliquam, viverra dolor quis, auctor metus. Cras nec euismod nulla.

Duis sed ultrices erat. Sed semper lorem vel turpis aliquam vulputate. Nam ornare mauris a lorem posuere, id ultrices erat fringilla. Morbi eget posuere felis. Donec semper odio vitae porta bibendum. Duis sit amet metus at ligula iaculis pretium. Quisque at consectetur tortor. Etiam nec nisi porttitor, dignissim odio quis, condimentum risus. Quisque ipsum ipsum, pulvinar vel mi non, semper fringilla lacus. Mauris vestibulum mauris semper mauris venenatis, vitae suscipit dolor tincidunt. Aliquam eget mi lacus.

Nullam hendrerit sem ligula, sit amet malesuada ipsum rhoncus ut. Aenean urna nisl, finibus at arcu a, posuere aliquet odio. Fusce mollis dapibus leo, non aliquam tellus facilisis sit amet. Nunc commodo mauris eu gravida vehicula. Vestibulum sagittis magna orci, in tempus urna lacinia ut. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque ultrices, tellus sed laoreet tincidunt, urna mi facilisis sapien, a pretium lacus leo vitae elit.
       </div>
       </div>     
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JSFiddle project.

I just added the following to your CSS file. Hope this helps and is kind of self explaining.

```
    .js-small-content {
        position:absolute;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        height:130px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I dont want to be able to scroll within the div I want it to be related like in the example above. But thank you for taking the time to answer!